# User-defined type that refer to it self with Cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, user-defined-types, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using Cassandra with Spring Data.
In my example I have a UDT named Person that has a field named "friend" of the same type:

```
@UserDefinedType("person")
public class Person {
    @Column("name")
   private  String name;

   @Column("surname")
   private  String surname;

   @Column("best_friend")
   private Person bestFriend;
}
```

When I run my test the log said that a UDT "person" doesn't exist.
To solve the issue I defined a second UDT named PersonFriend, and I added getter and setter to transform the Person instance starting from PersonFriend UDT. 
But I'm trying to use Cassandra in an opensource project, so, I wouldn't change the given model.

Thanks and Merry Christmas,
Davide :)

Comment: Do you want to file an issue https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACASS so we can see what we can do here?